# Trying to cycle through jobs with a button press

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

Please forgive the beginner question. I only heard the word Python 2 weeks ago.

I am trying to write a python 2.7 script that has two jobs which run in the AM and PM.  This is a reminder program that reminds me every day at 9am and 9pm. It also reminds me hourly after that. I want to try and figure out a way that a GPIO button press will stop the current job, but allow the next scheduled job to occur.  The idea is that these two jobs run every day, but a button press says, "Stop this job and wait for the next scheduled job". Once I do what the reminder has "reminded me", a button press stops the nagging.

Here is the basic code I've started writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import schedule  
import time  
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  

# GPIO 23 set up as input. It is pulled up to stop false signals  
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  

def am_job():  
    print 'This is the AM job'  

def pm_job():  
    print 'This is the PM job'  

schedule.every().day.at("9:00").do(am_job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(am_job)
schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(am_job)
schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(am_job)
schedule.every().day.at("13:00").do(am_job)

schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(pm_job)
schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(pm_job)
schedule.every().day.at("23:00").do(pm_job)


# I need to figure out a way that this button press cancels the current job
# but allows the next job to continue.
# Over and over each am and pm
GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback="some job name here", bouncetime=400)

try:
   while True: # This currently just cycles through all the jobs
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:  
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided that the above question was not going to work. Instead, I made two different Python scripts (am and pm). I then scheduled each with Cron.  In each script, I programmed a button press interrupt which exited the script.  This works great